# Аналог std::map с минимальным расходом памяти

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, map

Существует ли аналог `std::map` с оптимизацией по используемой памяти?

Проблема в том, что `std::map` в gcc 6.3 имеет размер в 48 байт, и получается большой перерасход памяти на каждый элемент.

Comment: Аналог есть, не столь быстрый, да. Это массив ключ-значение. Всего 16 байт на элемент, если ключ и значение - указатели, для amd64. Это, кстати, не смешно. Все зависит от задачи. Поиск по значению (в вашем случае это ключ) в упорядоченном массиве имеет такую же логарифмическую сложность, как и поиск в `map`.

Answer (score 5):

В этом мире за все приходится если не платить - то потом расплачиваться...

В `map` плата взимается не только за скорость, но и универсальность. Если у вас, например, много поисков, а вставка элементов разовая - то можно взять вектор, отсортировать, и потом искать с тем же O(log N), но без лишней траты памяти. Или разработать идеальную хеш-функцию и искать и вовсе за O(1). Словом, знание *конкретной* задачи может подсказать другие решения.

Но если вам нужно постоянно вставлять, удалять, искать - то бесплатно это не достичь. Либо ценой памяти, либо ценой снижения скорости каких-то операций, либо... Либо все вместе.

Словом, как в том слогане - "Пишем программы быстро, качественно, дешево. Ваше дело - выбрать два нужные критерия из трех..."

Comment: Добавлю, что *идеальная хеш-функция* — это не сарказм, а [реально существующий термин](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%98%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: @Arhad Ну, я именно это и имел в виду :)

Comment: мы-то знаем; а те, для кого такое понятие в новинку, попросту не поймут. Вот и пояснил.